# Why are our dynamic subdomains returning a 403 forbidden error when accessed?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

We are trying to make subdomains attached to their directory counterparts with the same name, so we have done this with our .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .domain.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://domain.com/%0" [L,P]


DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to make an attempt to access a subdomain, direct the user to the directory. But our problem is everytime we try to access ANY subdomain, we get a 403. We're using Apache on Debian. Wildcard in DNS working, but don't know how to specify it within the Virtual Host.

Comment: I'm not sure i got it. For instance, you have `http://user.domain.com` and you want it to be internally rewritten to `http://domain.com/user/` ? Anyway, first make sure your main domain and wildcard are pointing to the same document root. Then, i see you're using `P` flag (which is not mandatory in your case). You have several syntax errors in your code, i'll post a correct answer when i'm sure i understood your problem

Comment: Kind of. I want to go to user.domain.com in my browser, but somehow be shown the subdirectory with the same name (domain.com/user)

Comment: Yes that's what i said

Comment: Ya I revised my reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in document root folder)

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .domain.com
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(?:www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

This code will internally rewrite every subdomain (except `www`, `ftp` and `mail`) to its subfolder equivalent.

Example: http://user.domain.com/something will be internally rewritten to `/user/something`

**Note: make sure wildcard is pointing to the same document root as main domain**

Comment: Well, that's not possible since i didn't define this behaviour anywhere. Did you try my code with only editing `domain` ? Do you have other rules in your htaccess ? Does your `user` subfolder exist ?

Comment: Yes. No and I dynamically create the subdirectory ya.

Comment: I don't know what's happening :(

Comment: I forgot something in my code. Could you try my edited answer ?

Comment: Do you get an error ? Could you look at your apache logs (access/errors) ? Or rewrite logs if you enabled it

Comment: Yes Name virtual Hosts in my sites - available doesn't include any virtual Hosts

Comment: I have cloud flare could that be a problem

Comment: I did not understand the error you get. Does this mean you have a configuration problem ? For instance, make sure your wildcard subdomains (any of them) are going on the same place as root main domain

Comment: no matter what sub domain I put even if the folder is present or not it still redirects to the main homepage

Comment: Please answer my question. Did you configure your wildcard document root correctly ? If you remove the htaccess file, any subdomain (for instance `mytest.domain.com`) should display the same content as `www.domain.com` or `domain.com`). I suspect there's a problem there

Comment: Yes if I remove the htaccess mytest.domain.com is displaying domain.com content